# Init Custom inner object using spring bean xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have this kind of class:

```
Class Food
  int type
  String name

Class Dog
   String dogName
   Food food
```

I want to Init the `Dog` class using Spring properties, I have no problem to init the `dogName` value by doing this:

```
<bean id="dog" class="....Dog"> 

 <property name="dogName" value="dog"/> 

...

</bean>
```

How to set a value for the `Food` Object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ref in  to refer to the bean id of the food.

```
    <bean id="food" class="....Food"></bean>

    <bean id="dog" class="....Dog"> 
        <property name="dogName" value="dog"/> 
        <property name="food" ref="food"/> 
    </bean>

     <bean id="dog" class="c...dog">
        <property name="dogName" value="dog"/> 
        <property name="food" >
            <bean  class="...food">
               <property name="type" value="1"/> 
               <property name="name" value="chicken"/> 
            </bean>
        </property>
     </bean>
```

and in case of inner but you can't use it outside of the parent bean tag

```
 <bean id="dog" class="c...dog">
    <property name="dogName" value="dog"/> 
    <property name="food" >
        <bean  class="...food">
           <property name="type" value="1"/> 
           <property name="name" value="chicken"/> 
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<property name="food">
    <bean class="...Food">
      <property name="type" value="1"/>
      <property name="name" value="Apple"/>          
    </bean>
  </property>
```

See Spring [3.3.2.3. Inner beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-collection-elements):

> A  element inside the  or  elements is used to define a so-called inner bean. An inner bean definition does not need to have any id or name defined, and it is best not to even specify any id or name value because the id or name value simply will be ignored by the container.
>
> ```
> <bean id="outer" class="...">
>   <!-- instead of using a reference to a target bean, simply define the target bean inline -->
>   <property name="target">
>     <bean class="com.example.Person"> <!-- this is the inner bean -->
>       <property name="name" value="Fiona Apple"/>
>       <property name="age" value="25"/>
>     </bean>
>   </property>
> </bean>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ref` in `<property>` to refer to the bean id of the food.

```
<bean id="food" class="....Food"> 

</bean>

<bean id="dog" class="....Dog"> 
    <property name="dogName" value="dog"/> 
    <property name="food" ref="food"/> 
</bean>
```